# Overlapping button fires background button event

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm pretty new to Ionic and am a little confused as to how to fix the issue I have.  Basically I have a div that has an ng-click directive associated with it that does some arbitrary task.  Within that div I have a settings button which pulls up an actionsheet.  The issue is that when I click on the settings button it firstly fires the ng-click from the div and then it fires it's own ng-click event.

What I'd like is for the settings button to only fire it's own event which is to open the actionsheet.

This is the code:

```
<div class="groupBack" style="background-color:yellow" ng-click="doSomething()">
          <a class="button button-icon icon ion-android-menu" ng-click="show()"></a>
          <div class="centeredText">Some Text</div>
      </div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Try using the `event.stopPropagation()` in your `show()` function.  If you have no arguments being passed, the `event` will be your only argument to the `show()` function. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation

Comment: Hi Rob, that does resolve the issue.  Thanks!  Can I ask if i'm doing this the correct way?

Comment: If you really need to have the button in another element that also has a click listener then yes this is the correct way.  Remember you will need to `stopPropagation` on any `click` event you are listening to within the parent that you don't want bubbling up to the parent `div`

Comment: Great.  Much appreciated and thank you for the prompt help